# Call MPI_ABORT from exception destructor?

Tags: c++, exception, mpi

I have a large (quite complex ...) C++/MPI codebase. Parts of this code has developed into a do-not-throw exceptions zone because the MPI application will deadlock when one process throws an uncatched exception - in the case of uncaught exception I just want entire application (including all MPI processes to terminate). As I understand it the `MPI_ABORT(MPI_COMM_WORLD)` call will terminate all MPI processes - I have been toying with a custom exception like this:

```
class my_exception {
public:
    explicit my_exception(const std::string& m) :
        msg(m)
    {}

    ~my_exception() {
        if (!this->handled)
           Mpi_abort();
    }
    
    void handle() {
        this->handled = true;
    }

private:
    std::string msg;
    bool handled{false};
}
```

The purpose of this is to ensure that `MPI_ABORT()` is called for *uncaught* exceptions. In the case exceptions are indeed caught the
`catch` block must mutate the state of the exception object to ensure safe destruction - that is "OK". It is also "OK" that the application goes down in flames - the present deadlock is even worse.

I have not tried this out - but would be interested if someone up front could judge whether it is feasible at all. Alternative ways to avoid the deadlock is also more than welcome.

Comment: You say that `catch` block is required. Wouldn't then be better to explicitly call `MPI_Abort` in such a catch block? I believe it would be at least more understandable. Also, how will this solution work with exceptions of other type (such as `std::bad_alloc` etc.)?

Comment: The `catch` block and the `exception_instance.handle()` call is required to avoid calling `MPI_Abort()` - if the exception is not handled `MPI_Abort()` should be called and the entire application go up in flames.

Comment: It will probably not work well with other exceptions like `std::bad_alloc` - but that is the situation right now as well - i.e. currently throwing e.g. `std:bad_alloc()` will lead to a *deadlock* in a subsequent MPI call ine one of the processes part of the application.

Comment: And wouldn't be better to "wrap" the functionality of `main` by `try` block and call `MPI_Abort` in its `catch` block? It would cover all exceptions regardless of their types. We use such an approach in our HPC apps as well, since deadlock can waste a lot of supercomputing resources, which are typically highly limited.

Comment: To *wrap* main was a very good idea! If you make that an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0):

The comment from @Daniel Langr about wrapping main was a better alternative

Comment: Sorry, I was out of Stack Overflow for a while. Self-answering your own question is perfectly fine.